# returned non-zero exit status 2 problom in 'py -m build'

Tags: python

i'm beginner for python so i don't know anything.

i'm trying to do the "Packaging Python Projects"

but during the Generating distribution archives (py -m build),

this error occurred.

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\**\AppData\Local\Temp\build-env-3vnc67mr\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\base_command.py", line 216, in _main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "C:\Users\**\AppData\Local\Temp\build-env-3vnc67mr\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\uninstall.py", line 89, in run
    uninstall_pathset = req.uninstall(
  File "C:\Users\**\AppData\Local\Temp\build-env-3vnc67mr\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\req\req_install.py", line 678, in uninstall
    dist = get_distribution(self.req.name)
  File "C:\Users\**\AppData\Local\Temp\build-env-3vnc67mr\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\utils\misc.py", line 501, in get_distribution
    dist = search_distribution(req_name)
  File "C:\Users\**\AppData\Local\Temp\build-env-3vnc67mr\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\utils\misc.py", line 492, in search_distribution
    packages = get_installed_distributions(skip=())
  File "C:\Users\**\AppData\Local\Temp\build-env-3vnc67mr\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\utils\misc.py", line 477, in get_installed_distributions
    return [d for d in working_set
  File "C:\Users\**\AppData\Local\Temp\build-env-3vnc67mr\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\utils\misc.py", line 478, in <listcomp>
    if local_test(d) and
  File "C:\Users\**\AppData\Local\Temp\build-env-3vnc67mr\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\utils\misc.py", line 386, in dist_is_local
    return is_local(dist_location(dist))
  File "C:\Users\**\AppData\Local\Temp\build-env-3vnc67mr\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\utils\misc.py", line 566, in dist_location
    egg_link = egg_link_path(dist)
  File "C:\Users\**\AppData\Local\Temp\build-env-3vnc67mr\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\utils\misc.py", line 542, in egg_link_path
    if not virtualenv_no_global() and user_site:
  File "C:\Users\**\AppData\Local\Temp\build-env-3vnc67mr\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\utils\virtualenv.py", line 111, in virtualenv_no_global
    return _no_global_under_venv()
  File "C:\Users\**\AppData\Local\Temp\build-env-3vnc67mr\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\utils\virtualenv.py", line 72, in _no_global_under_venv
    cfg_lines = _get_pyvenv_cfg_lines()
  File "C:\Users\**\AppData\Local\Temp\build-env-3vnc67mr\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\utils\virtualenv.py", line 55, in _get_pyvenv_cfg_lines
    return f.read().splitlines()  # avoids trailing newlines
UnicodeDecodeError: 'cp949' codec can't decode byte 0xec in position 16: illegal multibyte sequence
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\**\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\build\__main__.py", line 372, in main
    built = build_call(
  File "C:\Users\**\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\build\__main__.py", line 229, in build_package_via_sdist
    sdist = _build(isolation, builder, outdir, 'sdist', config_settings, skip_dependency_check)
  File "C:\Users\**\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\build\__main__.py", line 140, in _build
    return _build_in_isolated_env(builder, outdir, distribution, config_settings)
  File "C:\Users\**\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\build\__main__.py", line 104, in _build_in_isolated_env
    with _IsolatedEnvBuilder() as env:
  File "C:\Users\**\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\build\env.py", line 105, in __enter__
    executable, scripts_dir = _create_isolated_env_venv(self._path)
  File "C:\Users\**\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\build\env.py", line 278, in _create_isolated_env_venv
    _subprocess([executable, '-m', 'pip', 'uninstall', 'setuptools', '-y'])
  File "C:\Users\**\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\build\env.py", line 82, in _subprocess
    raise e
  File "C:\Users\**\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\build\env.py", line 79, in _subprocess
    subprocess.check_output(cmd, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
  File "C:\Users\**\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 419, in check_output
    return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True,
  File "C:\Users\**\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 523, in run
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args,
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['C:\\Users\\**\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\build-env-3vnc67mr\\Scripts\\python.exe', '-m', 'pip', 'uninstall', 'setuptools', '-y']' returned non-zero exit status 2.

ERROR Command '['C:\\Users\\**\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\build-env-3vnc67mr\\Scripts\\python.exe', '-m', 'pip', 'uninstall', 'setuptools', '-y']' returned non-zero exit status 2.

------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

i think i'm might solve the first error

but the second error is what i don't understand.

i tried to search up this error message and i couldn't find appropriate solution.

how am i solve this?

Comment: cp949 is Hangul.  Does your username contain Hangul characters?

Comment: yes. i'll fix that soon but i don't know how to fix the second one

Comment: It's possible both issues have the same cause.

Comment: i fixed the first error but the second error is still there

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.